# Block all websites except 1 USG-3P Firewall

Tags: ubiquiti, unifi

i am trying to block all web (HTTP & HTTPS traffic) to and from a computer on our network - except for 1 website. I am using a USG-3P and in the firewall rules, I add the following 2 rules (in order):

```
Internet In, Before Predefined Rules, Accept, All IPv4 Protocol
Source Type Port/IP Group, IPv4 Address Group [WEBSITE IP ADDRESS], Port Group "Web" [80, 443]
Destination Type IP Address IPv4 Address [MACHINE LOCAL IP ADDRESS]

Internet In, Before Predefined Rules, Reject, All IPv4 Protocol
Source Type Port/IP Group, IPv4 Address Group Any, Port Group "Web" [80, 443]
Destination Type IP Address IPv4 Address [MACHINE LOCAL IP ADDRESS]
```

This does not seem to work. Does anyone have any ideas? Just trying to completely block all web traffic to a single computer on the network except for 1 website.

Thanks.

Comment: redirect port 80,443 to a proxy like in my example squid and use squidguard to deny all. you may also force this behavior by intercept the dns and or using a firewall like sophos utm/xgs that allows white instead of blacklisting. Remind that home and end-user computing questions are off topic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com instead

Answer (score 0):

```
    Rule 1 (Allow access to 
    specific website):
    Action: Accept
    Source: IPv4 Address Group [WEBSITE IP ADDRESS], Port Group "Web" [80, 443]
    Destination: IPv4 Address [MACHINE LOCAL IP ADDRESS]
    Rule 2 (Block all other web traffic): 
    Action: Drop
    Source: Any
    Destination: IPv4 Address [MACHINE LOCAL IP ADDRESS], Port Group "Web" [80, 443]
```

---

Make sure the accept has priority over the drop

---

I think you should do it like above

Comment: Thanks. Are these "Internet In" rules? For Rule 2, Source Port Group set to Any?

Comment: And yes, i have the accept rule over the drop rule.

Comment: Yes, these rules are intended for incoming internet traffic (Internet In). For Rule 2, you can indeed set the Source Port Group to "Any" because you want to block all incoming traffic regardless of the source port. This ensures that all web traffic destined for the specified machine's local IP address on ports 80 and 443 is blocked, except for the traffic allowed by Rule 1.